# Merging image causing black artefact in background

Tags: php, gd

Very new to php and im trying to merge two images together using GD.

I have tried doing this, however it is causing the merged image to have a weird black background.

Anyone know where i am going wrong?

```
    <?php
        $image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
        $overlay = imagecreatefrompng('image2.png');
        $size = getimagesize('image2.png');

        imagecopy($image_1, $overlay, 0, 0, 0, 0, $size[0], $size[1]);
        imagepng($image_1, "mergedImage.png");
    ?>
    <img src="image.png"/>
    <img src="image2.png"/>
    <img src="mergedImage.png">
```

This is the output i get.
[image]

source images:

[image][image]

Comment: Typically this is caused by alpha channel settings. But it's impossible to check without the source images. Can you edit those into your question?

Comment: Ive added them @timclutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telling GD to retain alpha channel information immediately after creating your target image should fix the issue:

```
<?php
$image_1 = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');
imagesavealpha($image_1, true);
$overlay = ...
```

At the moment you end up with a duplicate of `image2.png`, but I assume you want to achieve a different result:

[image]

Comment: Yeah that fixed it. Thank you